# How can i export file from wireshark to display not in hex format

Tags: export, wireshark

I'm trying to export file from wireshark, so I can search in it.

Every option I try doesn't give simple raw format as the tcp raw view, when I follow the TCP stream.

All it gives me is a hex view of the packets and the string in this kind of format breaks which can't be searched. I want it to export to a searchable format.

Can it be done?

This is what I'm getting now :

```
0000  48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 20 35 30 30 20 49 6e 74   HTTP/1.1 500 Int
0010  65 72 6e 61 6c 20 53 65 72 76 65 72 20 45 72 72   ernal Server Err
0020  6f 72 0d 0a 44 61 74 65 3a 20 54 68 75 2c 20 31   or..Date: Thu, 1
0030  30 20 4e 6f 76 20 32 30 31 31 20 31 36 3a 33 32   0 Nov 2011 16:32
0040  3a 35 37 20 47 4d 54 0d 0a 50 72 61 67 6d 61 3a   :57 GMT..Pragma:
0050  20 6e 6f 2d 63 61 63 68 65 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65    no-cache..Conte
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using TShark, sed and tr?
tshark -r Clmt_04.pcap -x -R "frame.number<40" | sed 's/^.{56}//' | tr -d '\n' > Clmt-04.txt
tshark -x
add output of hex and ASCII dump (Packet Bytes)
sed 's/^.{56}//'
remove the first 56 characters of each line
tr -d '\n'
remove new line character
Hope this helps

Comment: tshark -R is now deprecated. What would be used in it's place now?

Comment: tshark -r Clmt_04.pcap -x -R "frame.number<40".
tshark: -R without -2 is deprecated. For single-pass filtering use -Y.
tshark -r Clmt_04.pcap -x -Y "frame.number<40".
See also [TShark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) man-pages: -Y <displaY filter>

Comment: Whoops, forgot to mention I found a completely different solution that was way simpler. Anyone interested?

Answer (score 0):

After you identify the tcp stream, you can use the following command with **tshark**:

```
tshark -nr <file>.pcapng -q -z follow,tcp,ascii,XXXX
```

Where XXXX is the tcp stream.